# ListView error during debug but fragment does not extend ListView

Tags: android

I have a fragment but every time I try to test the app, it crashes when I click on the fragment and gives an Android Runtime Exception, saying that my content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.List'. However, my code for the fragment looks like this:

```
 public class MiscellaneousFragment extends Fragment {

    public MiscellaneousFragment(Context ctx){
        this.getActivity();
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.misc,container,false);
        return myFragmentView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

so why am I getting this error? How can I fix this? thank you`

Comment: 1. What is your Activity type?
2. Can you post the xml layout file misc.xml?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before when extending a `ListActivity` incorrectly.  I could be off, since your `Activity` code isn't posted, but from the error you've mentioned it could possibly be that you haven't declared a `ListView` correctly in your XML.  From the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

> `ListActivity` has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

Comment: I fixed it, it was an error in my another java class which created all the fragments. my code thought the fragment I was clicking on was another fragment. Although, where can I see what line-number an error is occurring on in the log cat?

Comment: Each line in a logcat stack trace will look similiar to:  01-14 16:53:37.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13479):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95), the line is after the colon Handler.java:__